# SonarQube AnnotationTree

Tags: annotations, sonarqube

I'm making rule custom rule using SonarJava. Rule purpose is checking methods. If method is annotated with @Test it also needs to have @TestInfo annotation with not empty testCaseId parameter. For that I'm using ANNOTATION kind and AnnotationTree.

But there is one problem. I can't find how I should determine on what method this annotation is. So currently I'm getting method's firstToken().line() and lastToken().line() . After that I get annotation line and check if it is on that method or not.

**Is there any method I could possibly missed which would show me on what method this annotation is?**